# I just replaced my CV Axle and the now the brakes are making scary noises

Tags: toyota, brakes, corolla, abs, cv-joint

I have a 2011 Toyota Corolla and my CV joints were starting to make popping noises.  I replaced both driver and passenger axles.  The car drives fine, but after about 20MPH the brakes make weird noises and stopping the car is not a pleasant experience.  It sounds REALLY bad, but does stop.  I have taken everything back apart and do NOT see any issues with the brake lines or the ABS speed sensor cable.

I have no idea what could be the problem, as there are no lights or codes that are on.  I can only assume it is the ABS, but no way to prove or sure why it would be an issue.

ANY HELP IS GREATLY APPRECIATED!

**EDIT 1:**

Here are the DTC's

C1413 Front Speed Sensor RH circuit output

C1422 Master Cylinder Pressure Sensor Zero Point High

Comment: Can you describe the noise and explain why stopping is not pleasant?  Does it pull to one side?  Does it take longer to stop than normal?

Comment: Any chance a brake pad is installed backwards?

Comment: I am familiar with ABS "pulsating" noise.  But this is different.  It kinda sounds like a grrrrr.  there is a pulsating sound to it however.  It does not pull to one side.  The fast I go, the worse it sounds.  It does seem to take a little longer to stop.

I jacked up the car, took off both tires and could NOT replicate the problem.  I was able to turn the driver side wheel forward and back.,  it did turn the passenger side.  But when I turned the passenger side wheel forward, the driver side wheel barely turned.  When turning the passenger side in reverse, the driver side turned equally.

Comment: also, with the tires off and the car in drive, minimum throttle, the traction control kept lighting up.

I have yet to see any ABS lights

The sounds seem to come from the left side of the car and not the right.  but when in the car, it almost seems to come from underneath the car.

I am lost, and I need my car running, I have to work this week!!

Comment: I didnt remove the caliper, brake pads or rotor.  So I would not think the problem could lie there.  I also did NOT remove the speed sensor, since nothing I had read indicated that I should.  Could this be the problem?

Also, the hub nut is tightened down the same distance on both axles. But my torque wrench only goes to 125LBS so I cannot say with 100% certainty I have that correct.

Comment: The traction control is probably operating because the drive wheels are not turning at the same speed due to being off the ground.  It may also be seeing that the rear wheels are not turning.  When you rotated the wheels by hand, do they both turn freely?

Comment: Did you carry out a similar process to this video - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=oXdbWiEYmso

Comment: @HandyHowie - both wheels rotate freely and easily

Comment: yes, this is how I did the install.  I did NOT grease the splines before inserting the shaft however.  Also after more testing, I truly feel the noise I am hearing is my ABS system and NOT the CV axles, I replaced.  The ABS lights are NOT on, but I do wonder about the chopper wheel and the teeth on CV Axle. could this be the issue?

Comment: UPDATE:  I drove the car and exceeded 50MPH.  In doing so, the ABS and traction control lights came on.  now the noise has stopped when braking, so I am going to take the car to Advanced Auto or somewhere that can read the code.  I will post the results as soon as I can.

Comment: I have used an OBDII to read the codes.  They are "C1413 Front Speed Sensor RH cicuit output" and "c1422 Master Cylinder Pressure Sensor Zero Point High"  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely the sound the car is making is the wheel bearing or the rotor hitting, torque spec for the front axle nut is 158 ft.lbs.

The C1422 probably occurred from a low voltage situation and the sensor needs to be re-calibrated.

C1413 is probably due to the axle nut being loose.